# SQL Outer Join in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, outer-join

I've got the following LINQ Query

```
from s in db.tblSave
 join a in db.tblAssessment on s.AssessmentID equals a.Id
 join staff in db.tblStaff on s.StaffID equals staff.Id
 join student in db.tblStudent on s.StudentID equals student.Id
 join signed in db.tblSaveSigned on s.Id equals signed.SaveID
 select new
 {
 SaveID = s.Id,
 StaffName = staff.StaffName,
 AssessmentName = a.AssessmentName,
 StudentName= student.StudentName,
 CreatedDate = s.CreatedDate,
 SignedDate = signed.SignedDate}
```

tblSaveSigned may not have a record against tblSave which is excluding some tblSave records. How do I include all tblSave records in my results? It's an outer join in SQL but not sure how to do it in LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Is there an SQL to LINQ tool?

Comment: Yeah! LinqPad, etc.

Comment: I've got LinqPad 5, the free version and can't see it? I know it does LINQ to SQL but can't find the reverse.

Comment: LINQPad can help you see what is wrong with your LINQ. Your LINQ in your question is incomplete, without the rest of the query it is hard to say how to proceed, but in general you add something like 'into signedj from signed in signj.DefaultIfEmpty()'

Comment: Didn't think the select part was that relevant but I've updated my code now to include it. Ok i'll give something like that a try in LINQPad. Thanks.

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct LINQ Query for put FULL OUTER JOIN on tblSave for tblSaveSigned. Thanks for NetMage for pointing me in the right direction.

```
from s in db.tblSave
 join a in db.tblAssessment on s.AssessmentID equals a.Id
 join staff in db.tblStaff on s.StaffID equals staff.Id
 join student in db.tblStudent on s.StudentID equals student.Id
 join signed in db.tblSaveSigned on s.Id equals signed.SaveID into signedj
 from signed in signedj.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new
 {
 SaveID = s.Id,
 StaffName = staff.StaffName,
 AssessmentName = a.AssessmentName,
 StudentName= student.StudentName,
 CreatedDate = s.CreatedDate,
 SignedDate = signed.SignedDate}
```

Comment: Next challenge: ditch the joins and use navigation properties.

Comment: Note that is actually a LEFT OUTER JOIN from (tblSave join tblAssessment join tblStaff join tblStudent join tblSaveSigned) to signedj. A FULL OUTER JOIN would include all records in signedj even if there was no match in tblSave.